# Implementing chat in webapp using converse.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, openfire, converse.js

I was trying to create a web based chat application using Openfire + BOSH + Converse.js technique with html,css,javascript support. As the first step I have done setting up openfire and I have downloaded source code of converse.js . Now I am stuck with BOSCH Configuration manager and impl;ementing chat with code. anybody have idea on this? Please help . I am really a fresher to this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set up http binding on openfire and put yourhostname:7070 as a bosh service url in your html.
this could help more: https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2954